# how to install components in angular 1 as you do in angular 2,3,4

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm fighting with and angular 1 project in order to fix a bug in push notifications function, I would like to do it by using firebase but I just can't find a tutorial that explains how to implement FCM with angular 1, so I'm trying to adapt myself to this.

I need to know how to do this (since is a .ts file);

```
import { Injectable }          from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth }     from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'
```

but in angular 1 (js file), because I need to use those componentes from dependencies.

Any idea?

Comment: what does the code you posted have to do with using firebase with angular1? you should look up how to use firebase with angular1. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject

Comment: I think you should start by looking at this : https://github.com/firebase/angularfire